# Until when you can listen to music on lag baomer?

Tags: halacha, music, lag-ba-omer

Until when can you listen to music on lag baomer?

Comment: I don't have a source but I think until midnight as this is how far not saying tachnun is extended to. For example in regards to tachanun in krias shema al hamita if one waited to go to sleep after chatzos following a day where there wasn't any tachanun at that point one would resume doing so. Again I have no source for this being connected to listening to music but it does follow logically

Comment: Assuming you hold the "2nd half of the Omer" I presume

Comment: @DannySchoemann Or Sefardim who hold of Lad? As I'm not among them, I'm not sure whether they get the day off, resume sefirah at night, and cease mourning entirely in the morning.

Comment: @DonielF - AFAIK the Sefardim hold like the Mechaber in סימן תצג that after Lad there's no mourning. נוֹהֲגִים שֶׁלֹּא לְהִסְתַּפֵּר עַד ל''ג לָעֹמֶר, שֶׁאוֹמְרִים שֶׁאָז פָּסְקוּ מִלָּמוּת, וְאֵין לְהִסְתַּפֵּר עַד יוֹם ל''ד בַּבֹּקֶר אֶלָּא אִם כֵּן חָל יוֹם ל''ג עֶרֶב שַׁבָּת שֶׁאָז מִסְתַּפְּרִין בּוֹ מִפְּנֵי כְּבוֹד הַשַּׁבָּת

Comment: @DannySchoemann Not after Lad - the night of Lad after the festivities of Lag.

Comment: @DonielF - I'm can't follow what you're getting at. But if you're asking how they celebrate Lag and then Lad, you have to ask them, as it contradicts written halacha as I know it.

Comment: @DannySchoemann Let's take this year as an example, with Lag on Sunday and Lad on Monday. What's the Halacha regarding Sunday night?

Comment: @DonielF - the halacha is very clear - וְאֵין לְהִסְתַּפֵּר עַד יוֹם ל''ד בַּבֹּקֶר - mourning continues from Pesach to Monday morning - with no break at all on Sunday. Shulchan Aruch orach Chaim 493:1 http://www.toratemetfreeware.com/online/f_01975_part_29.html#HtmpReportNum0064_L2

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you're referring to those people who keep the 2nd half of the Omer. Those people have to continue the mourning after Lag B'Omer.

I would assume that the day ends at sunset - just like every other Halachic day.